# Generating static map based on custom field data EE GMaps

Tags: add-on, google-maps-for-ee

Trying to create a static map dynamically in a channel entries loop with the lat/long field data. I'm thinking that the text fields are parsed after the `{exp:gmap:static_map center="{retailers_latitude},{retailers_longitude}"}` - any solution for this? Swapping parse order doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to encase those variables in quotes like:

```
{exp:gmap:static_map center="{retailers_latitude},{retailers_logitude}"}
```

Comment: This did work, however, in the `marker=""` parameter, it required just `marker="{lat}, {long}"`, for what it's worth. Thanks!